# Starting up Elasticsearch as a local node doesn't work

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm in the process of moving away from the REST API to the JAVA one (because we want to benefit from the data-less node advantages).

I tried to startup the local node in this way (boot seems fine to me):

```
 String localhostname = java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();

        ImmutableSettings.Builder settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder();


        settings.put("cluster.name", clusterName);

        //Node name
        settings.put("node.name", localhostname + "-eslocalnode");

        //This is key to configure a data less node
        /*

        # 3. You want this node to be neither master nor data node, but
        #    to act as a "search load balancer" (fetching data from nodes,
        #    aggregating results, etc.)
        #
        # node.master: false
        # node.data: false

         */
        settings.put("node.master", false);
        settings.put("node.data", false);

        /*

        # By default, multiple nodes are allowed to start from the same installation location
        # to disable it, set the following:
        # node.max_local_storage_nodes: 1

         */
        settings.put("node.max_local_storage_nodes", 1);

        /*

        # Set a custom port for the node to node communication (9300 by default):
        #
        # transport.tcp.port: 9300
         */
        if (tcpPort > 0)
            settings.put("transport.tcp.port", tcpPort);
        else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("tcpPort is not set");

        /*

        # Disable HTTP completely:
        #
        # http.enabled: false

        I don't want the HTTP api to be available on the local data-less nodes, so I disable it

         */

        settings.put("http.enabled", false);


        /**
         *
         * DISCOVERY PART!!!
         *
         *
         *
         */

        settings.put("discovery.zen.ping.timeout", discoveryPingTimeout);

        String unicastHostsArr[] = discoveryUnicastHosts.split("\\s*,\\s*");

        if (unicastHostsArr.length > 0)
            settings.put("discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts", unicastHostsArr);
        settings.put("discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled", false);
        Settings esSettings = settings.build();
        Node newNode = NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder().local(true).settings(esSettings).node();
        node = newNode.start();
```

(all variables are properly initialized I checked it). In particular, the unicastHosts are just one host that is our dev server (and it is filled with significant data) and the cluster name is the same.

Anyway if I attempt a search using like:

```
 Client client = node.client();
        ActionFuture<SearchResponse> searchFuture = client.search(new SearchRequest("journalindex"));
        SearchResponse search = searchFuture.get();
```

I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.elasticsearch.cluster.block.ClusterBlockException: blocked by: [SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/1/state not recovered / initialized];[SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/2/no master];
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.BaseFuture$Sync.getValue(BaseFuture.java:288)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.BaseFuture$Sync.get(BaseFuture.java:275)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.BaseFuture.get(BaseFuture.java:113)
    at com.netaporter.cms.estests.test.EsDataLessNodeTest.main(EsDataLessNodeTest.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

any idea on why this is happening?

Comment: is your variable ```clusterName``` the same for this node as the cluster you are trying to join? Does the log on the master node on your cluster indicate that this local node has joined (I am betting now). Are you sure that your ```unicastHostsArr``` list includes the master of your cluster and that the host/ip is hittable from this local node?

Comment: cluster is the same yes (and the variable gets set correctly). The host gets it, it worked once, but later it stopped.... maybe I'll post a solution when I'm done.